# After updating to Version 1.0.1, how can I successfully use "fill(previous)" to fill blank values in Apache IoTDB?

Tags: apache-iotdb, iotdb

Does anyone know that why the `fill(previous)` statement is not working for Version 1.0.1 of Apache IoTDB? I updated from Version 0.12, and when I tried the same statement, there is no effect and no blank value are filled. I need to filled this time series with blank values from the values docked by the previous time series. Anyone know are there any initialize operations I need to do to successfully use `fill(previous)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fill(previous)` in Apache IoTDB is to fill the value according to the original result set. If you need to fill in the value from the time series before your time of `null` values, you can expand the time range when querying in IoTDB.